# Difference between includes and hasOwnProperty in array search in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

What is the difference between `includes` and `hasOwnProperty` for searching an element in an `Array` in JS in terms of time and space complexity?

Both can be used to find whether an element exists in an `Array` or not.

Comment: `.hasOwnProperty()` checks for property *names*, not values.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise and is therefore nonsensical.

Comment: Since they search for completely different things, it makes no sense to compare their efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

`hasOwnProperty` returns a boolean value indicating whether the object on which you are calling it has a property with the name of the argument and as everyone The `includes()` method determines whether a string contains the characters of a specified string. include method returns true if the string contains the characters, and false if not. Also, it's the case sensitive.

and at the end, I think the question is based on a false assumption.

Answer (score -1):

> Both can be used to find whether an element exists in an Array or not.

Incorrect. `includes` checks if any of the elements in the array match the argument. `hasOwnProperty` checks to see if the *Array has a property* that matches the argument

```
$ const array = ['test', 'another'];
$ array.includes('test')
true
$ array.hasOwnProperty('test')
false
$ array.includes('length')
false
$ array.hasOwnProperty('length')
true
```

You can see that `includes` and `hasOwnProperty` do not return the same result, so it is pointless to compare efficiency.

Answer (score -2):

`includes` is checking if your array contains specified value, while `hasOwnProperty` checks if your array has specified property name in its __proto__:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.prop = 'Some prop';

arr.includes(2); // -> true
arr.hasOwnProperty(2); // -> false
arr.includes('prop'); // -> false
arr.hasOwnProperty('prop'); // -> true
```